# editing nanorc on OSX v10.9.5

Tags: syntax-highlighting, nano

On my VM, I have syntax highlighting in nano for perl, python, and bash.

I did this by adding

`include /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc`

to my ~/.nanorc file

However, I just bought a new Macbook pro, and /usr/share/nano does not exist at that location, despite that vim, emacs, etc. are in that location ...

find . -name "nano" returns ./usr/bin/nano, but this is only the executable (I think) and not the folder that I need containing the *.nanorc files.

Has anyone done this on 10.9.5 ?

Comment: if you're using `.nanorc`s from any non-BSD/non-Mac source with Apple nano, you may be getting only partial syntax coloring.  See the update to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Apple's nano, you can copy `.nanorc` files from any source to somewhere in your homedir, such as `~/.nano`.

The [nano-highlight repository](https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight) seems to be an attempt to collect all of the best syntax highlighting `.nanorc`s in one place.  Following [the directions there](https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight#so-htf-do-i-use-these-things) may be the simplest solution.

If you install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/)' nano, some `.nanorc` files are installed in `/opt/local/share/nano` (including a `python.nanorc`).

Most of the nano-highlight `.nanorc`s appear to be compatible with both Apple and MacPorts nano, with the exception that Apple nano (which is older) [doesn't understand the `bash.nanorc`](https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight/issues/17).  Either nano will segfault if you try to include *all* of them; I'm not sure if that bug is triggered by a particular `.nanorc`, but I suspect it's triggered by including too many (regardless of which ones).

---

**UPDATE:** The `.nanorc` files in the [nano-highlight repository](https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight) are only partly compatible with Apple nano.  Some of the colors will not be used, but no error will be given.  According to [this comment](https://github.com/serialhex/nano-highlight/issues/17#issuecomment-91371392) on the `bash.nanorc` bug, the problem is a result of differences between the BSD and POSIX regular expression syntaxes, and can be fixed by modifying all of the `.nanorc` files with this command:

```
sed -i -e 's|\<|[[:<:]]|g;s|\>|[[:>:]]|g' /path/to/nanorc/files/*
```

MacPorts nano is not affected (it uses a regular expression engine installed by MacPorts).